# What type of cacti is this?

Tags: cactus

I would like to know what variety of cactus this is. It has grown three times its height since I bought it and although I have looked on many websites, I just cannot seem to find anything like it.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's a Consolea rubescens. AKA Opuntia rubescens. Common name is "Roadkill cactus".

It will eventually grow into a large tree, so give it a lot of space. The green and brown cactus in front is Tephrocactus geometrizans

Comment: Roadkill cactus, great name for a flat cactus!

Comment: Thank you very much.